# Is there a pair of non-isomorphic structures each of which is isomorphic to an ultrapower of the other?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, ultrapowers

> Does there exist a pair of non-isomorphic structures $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ as well as sets $I$ and $J$ and ultrafilters $\mathcal{U}$ on $I$ and $\mathcal{F}$ on $J$ such that $\mathfrak{A}^I/\mathcal{U}\cong\mathfrak{B}$ and $\mathfrak{B}^J/\mathcal{F}\cong\mathfrak{A}$?

This question is inspired by the Keisler-Shelah theorem, which says that you can arrange $\mathfrak{A}^I/\mathcal{U} \cong \mathfrak{B}^J/\mathcal{F}$ (moreover you can arrange that $\mathfrak{A}^I/\mathcal{U}\cong \mathfrak{B}^I/\mathcal{U}$). The answer to this question very likely depends on set theoretic assumptions, so a reasonable weakening would be mere consistency relative to some strong set theoretic assumptions or in some forcing extension. Another reasonable weakening would be to ask about iterated ultrapowers rather than just ultrapowers.

On the other hand assuming a positive answer an obvious follow-up would be the question of the existence of a triple of pairwise non-isomorphic structures, each of which is isomorphic to ultrapowers of the other two. Another obvious follow-up is whether or not it can be arranged that $\mathfrak{A}^I/\mathcal{U}\cong\mathfrak{B}$ and $\mathfrak{B}^I/\mathcal{U\cong{\mathfrak{A}}}$, i.e. whether or not there exists a structure and an ultrafilter such that iterating ultrapowers by that ultrafilter alternates between two isomorphism classes.

Comment: We can assume $I=J$ by taking their union if necessary. Also, since both are $\frak A$ and $\frak B$ satisfy this being isomorphic to an ultrapower of the other, they have the same cardinality.

Comment: One goal post would be to look at the characteristics of ultrapowers which follow from properties of the ultrafliter, then try to take two ultrafilters which produce non-isomorphic ultrapowers (say of $\Bbb N$) and then iterate that with some complementing ultrafilters to get the wanted result.

Comment: What do you mean by 'complementing ultrafilters'?

Comment: I guess I don't know. But i would imagine it is something about solving the equation $U+x=F+y$ in $\beta\omega$, or something.

Comment: Quantifiers on $I$ and $J$ are missing. I guess the question means "as well as sets $I,J$ and...". But it also makes sense fixing $I$ and $J$ beforehand. Please clarify.

Comment: @YCor The first interpretation is the sensible one at this stage. Just as in the proof of the Keisler-Shelah theorem, one is not going to get the required situation if $I,J$ are given to us beforehand. (But, once one has an affirmative answer, this changes, as it then suffices that $I,J$ are large enough.)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo yes of course, but this site is no quiz to guess what a sensible interpretation is (and the question is meaningful, say with $I,J$ infinite countable).

Comment: @YCor (That comment about quizzes seems unnecessarily uncharitable on your part.) In any case, just as in the Keisler-Shelah result, I would expect precise bounds on the smallest possible size of $I,J$ to depend on set-theoretic considerations.

Comment: Hmm... actually, my first reply to @YCor is wrong, sorry, of course there are upper bounds on the size of $I,J$. Apologies. So $\mathfrak A,\mathfrak B$ must be reasonably saturated and yet not isomorphic...

Comment: I meant it in the sense of "as well as sets $I$, $J$ and...". I've edited the question.

Comment: A (trivial) restatement of the question: is there a structure $\mathfrak{A}$ and ultrafilters $\mathcal{U},\mathcal{F}$ such that $\mathfrak{A}$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{A}^{\mathcal{U}\cdot\mathcal{F}}$ but not $\mathfrak{A}^{\mathcal{U}}$?

Comment: Since we can assume that $I=J$, this gives us a reasonable notion of iterating the ultrapowers as an ultrapower itself, moreover the iteration is just taking the product of the ultrafilters in the Stone space (modulo some reasonable bijection of $I$ with $I^2$, that is). Which goes back to my remarks about solving some equations in the Stone space (although with multiplication rather than with addition), and with discerning properties of ultrapowers from properties of filters, etc.

Comment: I'd tend to guess that under the negation of CH (in ZFC), two suitable ultraproducts of the real field could work (one needs the negation of CH to have them non-isomorphic).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An example assuming large cardinals: suppose $U$ and $W$ are normal ultrafilters on a measurable cardinal $\kappa$ such that $(V_{\kappa+2})^{M_U}\neq (V_{\kappa+2})^{M_W}$, where $M_U$ denotes the transitive collapse of the ultrapower of $V$. Let $Z = U\times W$. Let $M$ be the iterated ultrapower of length $\omega$ hitting $Z$ and its images. Then $M = j_Z(M) = j_U(j_W(M))$. But $j_W(M)$ is not isomorphic to $M$ since $(V_{\kappa+2})^M = (V_{\kappa+2})^{M_U}\neq (V_{\kappa+2})^{M_W} = (V_{\kappa+2})^{j_W(M)}$. For any structure $N$ in the language of set theory and any ultrafilter $D$, $j_D(N)$ is isomorphic to the (external) ultrapower of $N$ by $D$. So $M^\kappa / W$ is not isomorphic to $M$ but $(M^{\kappa}/W)^\kappa/U$ is isomorphic to $M$, as desired. If you want to replace $M$ with a set sized structure, consider instead $(V_\lambda)^M$ where $\lambda$ is a fixed point of $j_Z$.

Comment: If you don't require $S$ to be a well-ordering, how do you iterate along it? (I vaguely recall hearing that one could do this, but I don't recall the details.)

Comment: @Noah I suppose you would need an appropriate directed system of embeddings and then you would use directed limits.

Comment: Why is $(V_{\kappa+2})^M = (V_{\kappa+2})^{M_U}$ and why is $(V_{\kappa+2})^{M_W} = (V_{\kappa+2})^{j_W(M)}$?

Comment: $V_{\kappa+2}^M = V_{\kappa+2}^{M_U}$ since the natural map $M_U \to M_Z \to M$ has critical point $j_U(\kappa)$. Since $V_\kappa^M = V_\kappa$, $V_{j_W(\kappa)}^{j_W(M)} = j_W(V^M_\kappa) = j_W(V_\kappa) = V_{j_W(\kappa)}^{M_W},$ which implies the second equality.